# Error concatenating datetime objects in an array

Tags: python

I'm developing a software to create a matrix with this structure : `[[2020-07-14 13:01:58.535695, 9.013799869442407, 989.5936121308639], [2020-07-14 14:40:05.144901, 59.27540855766542, 463.4158524443841]]`

To build the first line , the array should contains : `[2020-07-14 13:01:58.535695,2020-07-14 14:40:05.144901]`

To concatenate these datetime I do this:

```
x_vet = []
        for z in range(self.n_samples):
            self.x_0 = datetime.now()
            totaltime = self.x_0 + timedelta(milliseconds = self.period)
            x_vet.append(self.x_0 + totaltime)
        self.signals_data.append(x_vet)
```

The error is:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and
> 'datetime.datetime'

So I've tried to do this in the code:

```
x_vet.append(str(self.x_0) + str(totaltime))
```

But with `str()` I get only 1 element like that: `'2020-07-14 14:35:44.0007892020-07-14 14:35:44.010789'`

I want to get this in `x_vet` : `[2020-07-14 13:01:58.535695,2020-07-14 14:40:05.144901]`
Because the whole software is build to recognize `x_vet` as an array of 2 elements

This error appears only with datatime object, because at the start I've tried my program with float and was working and returned:

```
[[0.0, 9.013799869442407, 989.5936121308639], [0.01, 59.27540855766542, 463.4158524443841]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
x_vet = []

for z in range(self.n_samples):
    self.x_0 = datetime.now()
    totaltime = self.x_0 + timedelta(milliseconds = self.period)
    x_vet.append(totaltime)
self.signals_data.append(x_vet)
```